# Measurable-set-valued random variables and their relation to conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space.

I am seeking references on *measurable-set-valued random variables*. That is, I am interested in functions $X$ from $\Omega$ into $\mathcal F$. In order for such $X$ to be measurable, $\mathcal F$ must be equipped with a sigma-field. My first question, then, is:

> Is there a natural sigma-field for $\mathcal F$? Will $2^{\mathcal F}$ do?

Here is some partial motivation for the first question, which leads to a second question. Suppose that $X$ takes countably many values $F_1, F_2,...$ in $\mathcal F$. Suppose, moreover, that $F_n = \{\omega: X(\omega) = F_n\}$, so that $\{F_n\}$ is a countable partition of $\Omega$. Then, viewed as a function of $\omega$, $P(\cdot \mid X(\omega))$ is just a version of the regular conditional probability $P(\cdot \mid \mathcal A)$, where $\mathcal A$ is the sigma-field generated by the $F_n$.

In general, it won't be the case that $X$ takes only countably many values, however. And it won't be the case that the values $F$ of $X$ satisfy $F = \{X=F\}$. But $X$ always generates a sub-sigma-field $\sigma(X)$ of $\mathcal F$ in the usual way. Thus, a second question:

> What is the general relationship between the conditional probability $P(A \mid \sigma(X))$ and $P(A \mid X(\omega))$, viewed as a function of $\omega$?

Note that the quantity $P(A \mid X(\omega))$ is an elementary conditional probability, i.e. it is equal to $P(A \cap X(\omega))/P(X(\omega))$.

(For the purposes of addressing the last question, let us stipulate that $P(A \mid B)=P(A)$ whenever $P(B)=0$.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to answer the first questions in the more general context where $X\colon (\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\to\tilde{\Omega}$ is any map. Your case $\tilde{\Omega}=\mathcal F$ is just a special case.

If $X$ is fixed and you want to make it measurable, one natural choice for the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A_X$ on $\tilde{\Omega}$ is "the largest $\sigma$-algebra on $\tilde{\Omega}$ such that $X$ is measurable", i.e.
$$
\mathcal A_X := \{A\subseteq \tilde{\Omega}\mid X^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal F \}
$$
(it is a standard exercise to show that this actually defines a $\sigma$-algebra).

Concerning your second question:
Let us first fix $\omega\in\Omega$ and let $x_\omega := X(\omega)\in\mathcal F$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(A|\sigma(X))(\omega)
&=
P(A|X=x_\omega)
=
\frac{P(A\cap \{X=x_\omega)\} }{P(X=x_\omega)},
\\
P(A|X(\omega))
&=
\frac{P(A\cap x_\omega)}{P(x_\omega)}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, one condition that makes the two concepts agree, is 
$$
\{X=x_\omega \} = x_\omega\qquad \forall \omega,
$$
which is exactly your condition $F = \{X=F\}$ (note that the latter does not have to hold for all $F\in\mathcal F$, but only for $F\in{\rm ran}(X)$ in the range of $X$).
All of this also works without your stipulation at the end of your question as long as all objects exist (conditioning on events of measure zero is often well-defined).

Now, if this condition does not hold (as you write "it won't be the case that the values $F$ of $X$ satisfy $F = \{X=F\}$"), I don't see any natural relation between these two concepts, since the values in $F$ have nothing to do with those $\omega$ that map to $F$.

One interesting criterion that I thought through is the weaker condition
$$
\omega\in X(\omega)\qquad \forall \omega,
$$
which implies $\{X=x_\omega \} \subseteq x_\omega\ \forall \omega$. But even then there is nothing one can say about the relation of the two conditional probabilities, because conditioning on some event $A$ and conditioning on some event $B$ can give any two values in $[0,1]$ even for $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: What do you mean by ''$X = X(\omega)$''?

Comment: This is a typical short-hand notation for the following reasoning: For a fixed $A\in\mathcal F$, $Y=P(A|X)$ is a random variable. In order to define it, we have to say what $Y(\omega)$ is for each $\omega\in\Omega$. Let's fix $\omega$. Let $x = X(\omega)$, which is now a fixed element of $\tilde \Omega$. Define $Y(\omega)$ as the conditional probability $Y(\omega)=P(A|X=x)$. In short: $Y(\omega)=P(A|X=X(\omega))$.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. In general the two functions I asked about are not equal, as simple examples show.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. If you can give (a reference to) such a counterexample, I would be interested.

Comment: Let $\Omega = \{a,b\}$, $\mathcal F = 2^\Omega$, $P(a)=1/2=P(b)$, $X(a)=\{a\}$, $X(b) = \Omega$. Then, $\sigma(X) = \mathcal F$ and $P(a \mid \sigma(X))(b)=0$ while $P(a \mid X(b))=1/2$.

Comment: I like your example, but there is a mistake:
Let $\mathcal F = \big\{ f_0 = \emptyset, f_1 = \{a \}, f_2 = \{b\}, f_3 = \{a,b\} \big\}$, then $X(a) = f_1,\ X(b) = f_3$. Therefore, $P(\{a\}|X(b)) = P(\{a\}|X=f_3) = 0$ (and not $1/2$), because if $X=f_3$ then you cannot have started in $a$.

So it's the common confusion with power sets: $X = f_3$ does not mean "$X=a$ or $X=b$" (which would correspond to $X\in f_3$ and does not make sense).

Comment: There's no mistake in my example, and you are still misunderstanding the notation and/or concepts. It isn't true that $X(b) = \{X = f_3\}$. $\{X = f_3\} = \{b\}$ but $X(b) = \{a,b\}$. If there's any way that I can clarify my question, please feel free to let me know. Otherwise, I'd like to kindly ask you to delete your answer as it seems to me to only be perpetuating confusion.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification! I thought by $P(A|X(\omega))$ you meant $P(A|X)(\omega)$ which is defined by $P(A|X=X(\omega))$. But $P(A|X(\omega))$ makes sense in a different way here, since $X(\omega)\in\mathcal F$. Your edit of the question makes it very clear. I will try to give it some further thought. Sorry for the confusion! My bad..

Comment: Ok, now that I got your question right I edited my answer. I'm not sure you will gain much insight from it, because you seem to have thought most of it through already. But I just don't see any natural relation of the two concepts in the general case.